# MatLab Plot - add 0.1 to points with same coordinates

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

My question is:

I am plotting a matrix containing grades per assignment for students e.g. [assignments x grades], but if more than one student gets the same grade in the same assignment, the points will be on top of each other.  I want to add a small random number (between -0.1 and 0.1) to the x- and y-coordinates of each dot.

Comment: And what's stopping you? What have you done already and where are you stuck?

Comment: Have you considered using other means to show there are several coincident values? For example, increase dot size; or use vertical bars whose height is number of occurrences (i.e. a histogram)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do exactly what you requested, you could do something like this -

```
assignments = (1:10)'
scores = randi(10, 10, 20);
```

The original plot of assignment vs students scores -

```
plot(assignments, scores, '.b')
```

[image]

Adding a small random offset to each score -

```
plot(assignments, scores+0.2*(rand(size(scores))-0.5), '.b')
```

[image]

Finally, you could opt for a more complicated, but slightly prettier, solution -

```
counts = zeros(10, 10);
for i = 1:10
  for j = 1:10
    counts(i, j) = sum(scores(i,:)==j);
  end
end

figure();
hold on;
for i = 1:10
  for j = 1:10
    if counts(i,j) > 0
      plot(i, j, 'o', 'MarkerSize', 2*counts(i,j), 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b'); hold on;
    end
  end
end
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! Just a quibble: I'd make marker _area_ (not linear size) proportional to the count